# What's the terminology for this C construct: 'int myInt = ( { int x=42; x; } );'?

Tags: c, terminology, construct

I've just been shown a very neat C trick:

```
int myInt = ( { int x=42; x; } ); // sets myInt to 42
```

This is very useful for writing macros. But what exactly is going on here? Could someone pick this line apart and isolate/identify the mechanisms?

Comment: GNU extension, statement-expression. **It's not portable.**

Comment: Why is it useful for macros?

Comment: @JeffRSon: it allows you to put loops and other control statements into "expressions" resulting from macro expansion.  It gives you the same thing as inline functions, without the kind of namespace/scope controls that functions offer and enforce.  (My rule of thumb here is, use inline functions rather than GnuC statement-expressions whenever possible.)

Comment: @torek: thanks +1 , i didnt knew it could be used like that !!

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as `int myInt = 42;`. Just initializing with an expression whose value comes from x which has been initialized by 42.